# What seems the problem in my update function?

Tags: php, html, sql

The update function is working fine but it's not updating the database. I tried my best to fix it. What seems the problem?

```
// edit vaccine information
function updateVaccine($vac)
{
    // $vacc_id=$_POST['vacc_id'];
    // $vacc_name=$_POST['vacc_name'];
    // $vacctrade_name=$_POST['vacctrade_name'];
    // $vacc_type=$_POST['vacc_type'];
    // $vacc_target=$_POST['vacc_target'];
    // $vacc_dosage=$_POST['vacc_dosage'];

    $sqlUpd = "UPDATE vaccine 
            SET  vacc_name ='".$vac->getVacc_name()."',
            vaccTrade_name ='".$vac->getVacctrade_name()."',  
            vacc_type ='".$vac->getVacc_type()."',
            vacc_target ='".$vac->getVacc_target()."',
            vacc_dosage ='".$vac->getVacc_dosage()."' 
            WHERE vacc_id ='".$vac->getVacc_id()."' "; 
    
    $this->con->query($sql);
    
    echo "<script>alert('Vaccine Information Was Successfully Updated')</script>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh'content='0;url=vaccineInfo.php'>";
    $this->con->close();
}
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with parameter values:  **pass them in**.

Comment: How can it be "working fine" if it's not updating the database? That's all it's supposed to do, so if it doesn't do it, it's not working fine.

Comment: If you mean it's not reporting an error, that's because you never check for errors.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL-Server, PostGreSQL, etc.)? What PHP extension are you using to access it (mysqli, PDO, etc.)? Please add appropriate tags.